# Create a table in hive with timestamp as comment

Tags: hive, comments, create-table, beeline, hiveddl

I would like to create a table in hive, inside the comment include the creation date (current_timestamp function). Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ex.tb_test ( field1 int, field2 String) COMMENT current_timestamp STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

But it returns error: ILED: ParseException line 2: 8 mismatched input 'current_timestamp' expecting StringLiteral near 'COMMENT'

Do you know any way to add to the comment the creation date of the table?

Answer (score 1):

Functions are not supported in table DDL. You can pass pre-calculated timestamp as a `--hiveconf` parameter and use for example like this:  `comment '${hiveconf:ts}'`(it should be quoted), such parameter will be resolved as a string literal before command execution.

BTW Hive stores CreateTime.

`describe formatted table_name` command outputs `CreateTime` along with other table info.